# Waiting for a signal or timeout with bordeaux-threads

Tags: common-lisp

I use sbcl and i have a thread, that just performs a specific task (writes something into a file), falls into sleep for 30 seconds and repeats.

What i want to achieve is: If the user wants the program to stop, the thread shall wake up immediately, write to the file and stop itself.

Can anyone give me a hint?
kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Bordeaux-threads doesn't have such feature, so you should use the signal handling facilities of your implementation. Maybe [cl-signal-handler](https://github.com/orthecreedence/cl-signal-handler) can be useful. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950680/unix-signal-handling-in-common-lisp) for some additional details.